# Tor failed to establish a tor Tor network connection

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, connection

```
12/29/18, 17:21:54.324 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/29/18, 17:21:54.325 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/29/18, 17:21:54.325 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/29/18, 17:21:54.325 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/29/18, 17:21:54.325 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
12/29/18, 17:21:54.331 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
12/29/18, 17:21:54.573 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
12/29/18, 17:21:54.613 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
12/29/18, 17:21:54.725 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
12/29/18, 17:22:01.447 [WARN] Received directory with skewed time (DIRSERV:154.35.175.225:443): It seems that our clock is behind by 58 minutes, 35 seconds, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
12/29/18, 17:22:01.448 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus. (Clock skew -3515 in directory from DIRSERV; CLOCK_SKEW; count 2; recommendation warn; host ? at 154.35.175.225:443) 
12/29/18, 17:22:01.494 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/29/18, 17:22:01.495 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/29/18, 17:22:01.495 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Answer (score 0):

the messages are there for a reason... please read it and act accordingly:

> Received directory with skewed time (DIRSERV:154.35.175.225:443): It seems that our clock is behind by 58 minutes, 35 seconds, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings.

it seems that your clock is out of sync... please try to connect again (to rule out if it was a server issue), if you get the same error message again set the correct time on your machine. - IIRC your hardware clock should be in UTC!

Answer (score 0):

The situation can be as a result of the ISP attacks - yes, I see it periodically here in Russia for years, here is how it comes: NTP broadcast and/or local NTP server announce to the server with date back-stepping attack. It kills all SSL, basically, because the timestamps are becoming wrong and de-synchronized. To avoid it - just set up a local NTP server and use it for your time sync.